# Android Gradle - send variable to dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have gradle modules: app and library module libApp. Each one of them has own gradle file.
app.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
     prod {somevariable = false}
     debug {somevariable = true}
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':libApp')
}
```

And libApp.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    buildConfigField "boolean", "SOME_VARIABLE_FROM_APP_MODULE", somevariable
}
```

How to force gradle to compile project libApp in app module with somevariable dependent on product flavor ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with flavors.

In the library module's build.gradle, define a flavor dimension that corresponds to the variable's value:

```
android {
    /* ... */

    flavorDimensions "someVar"

    productFlavors {
        someVarTrue {
            dimension "someVar"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "SOME_VARIABLE_FROM_APP_MODULE", 'true'
        }

        someVarFalse {
            dimension "someVar"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "SOME_VARIABLE_FROM_APP_MODULE", 'false'
        }
    }
}
```

In the app module's build.gradle, define which app flavor should use which library flavor:

```
android {
    /* ... */

    flavorDimensions "environment"

    productFlavors {
        prod {
            dimension "environment"
        }

        dev {
            dimension "environment"
        } // note: naming a flavor "debug" might create a conflict with the default "debug" configuration
    }
}

dependencies {
    /* ... */
    prodImplementation project(path: ':libApp', configuration: 'someVarTrue')
    devImplementation project(path: ':libApp', configuration: 'someVarFalse')
}
```

You might want to see [this article](https://android.jlelse.eu/product-flavors-for-android-library-d3b2d240fca2) for some more details.

Comment: This will not work, because you have mistaken configuration with flavor name. someVarTrue must be declared in `configurations {}` block in library, but inside it we can't declare buildConfigFields. Are you sure that code above is correct ?

Comment: @taulus I've updated my answer, it should now work. Sorry, I was posting this from memory on a smartphone and messed up the syntax. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create `ext` block in your project level `build.gradle` which encapsulates custom properties and makes them available to all modules in the project.

```
ext {
    somevariable = true
}
```

While accessing it, you can simply

```
defaultConfig {
    buildConfigField "boolean", "SOME_VARIABLE_FROM_APP_MODULE", ext.somevariable
}
```

Comment: It will work BUT I want to change value of somevariable dependent on currently builded flavour.

Comment: You can set the variable in each flavour as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697154/gradle-android-plugin-add-custom-flavor-attribute)

Comment: @taulus just update the value per flavour and it should do the trick

Comment: @Sagar but it is not :/ It is behave like libApp is compiled once with somevariable value like in debug flavor - even if I am building prod.